# Emular subconsulta sin tabla principal en Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Yo puedo hacer esto en SQL Server:

```
SELECT 'HERRAMIENTA ELÉCTRICA' AS TIPO_PRODUCTO,
0 AS DEPRECIACION,
(select sum(empid) from HR.employees) STOCK
```

Pero en Access la misma consulta devuelve el siguiente error:

> Query input must contain at least one table or query

Entonces ¿cuál sería la mejor opción para emular esto? Hacer una consulta a una tabla X que tenga por lo menos un registro y en caso de tener más limitarlo suena sucio para mí, siguiendo lo que indica el error de que falta por lo menos una tabla en la consulta, por lo que busco una mejor forma de hacerlo.

PDTA: Pregunta basada en una pregunta que también he hecho en SO en inglés.

Comment: Hola Juan revisa acerca de Dual Table  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734142/query-input-must-contain-atleast-one-table-or-query

Comment: @Elenasys, por ahí va la respuesta, fantástico, lástima que no pude atinarle con las palabras con las que buscaba respuesta, checo y quizás yo mismo me conteste, gracias nuevamente :)!.

Comment: Por nada, sería excelente pongas la respuesta a tu pregunta, saludos!

Answer (score 5):

Puedes plantear la consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
    'HERRAMIENTA ELÉCTRICA' AS TIPO_PRODUCTO,
    0 AS DEPRECIACION,
    COALESCE(SUM(empid), 0) AS STOCK
FROM
    HR.employees;
```

De esta forma, logras proyectar lo que quieres sin hacer la subconsulta.

La prueba del concepto la tienes acá: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cce42/2/0

Comment: si la tabla está vacía, debe aparecer 'HERRAMIENTA ELÉCTRICA',0,0, con este query es eso lo que se muestra?.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla, no. Pero ahora que se como quieres el resultado, lo corrijo.

Comment: Es cierto estimado, sin embargo, tendré que poner el query exacto que estoy trabajando, hay un extraño comportamiento en Access, apenas me desocupe continuo con la verificación.

Answer (score 1):

Según recuerdo, Access no soporta esa clase de sintaxis... el dialecto SQL de Access exige que las consultas siempre tengan, cuando menos, `select ... from ...`.

Adicionalmente a [la solución propuesta por drielnox](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1003/emular-subconsulta-sin-tabla-principal-en-access/1006#1006), puedes crear una tabla "dummy" (si gustas, incluso puede estar oculta) que contenga una sóla fila, para tener siempre una tabla a la cual recurrir para estas circunstancias.